# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

Всем здрасьте. Плз хелп. В коде (ниже) пытаюсь проверить есть ли юзер в БД. При этом: если юзера в БД нет, то отправляется ответом "ОК для добавления" и можно спокойно отправлять следующий запрос. Если же юзер существует, то последующие запросы блокируются и выводится ответ из темы сабжа. Почему ? :((

```
app.post("/auth/register", async (req, res) => {
    const password = req.body.password;
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    const dbParams = {
        host: "localhost",
        user: "root",
        database: "blog_voyages",
        password: "",
    };

    const connection = mysql.createConnection(dbParams);

    connection.connect(function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.error("Error: " + err.message);
        } else {
            console.log("Connected to DB");
        }
    });

    
    await connection.execute("SELECT * FROM `utilisateurs`", (err, rows) => {
        rows.forEach(row => {
            if (row.login == req.body.login) {
                res.json('User exists');            
            }
        });
        res.json('OK to add');        
    });    
});
```

Comment: у вас программа идёт по массиву rows, если записей больше одной то программа больше одного раза посылает данные и заголовки `res.json('User exists')`. Переработайте подход или, например, напишите `select * from utilisateurs limit 1`

Comment: @nörbörnën так ведь как раз проблема в том, что записей в БД всего 3 для тестирования и они точно уникальные, зуб даю :). К тому же, как я писал в топике, после ответа 'OK to add' можно отправлять запрос еще сколько угодно раз, а если имя пользователя найдено, то только при первом запросе сервер отвечает, что пользователь существует, а уже при следующих (вне зависимости от того, вводишь существующего пользователя, или нет) - выкидывает ошибку headers already sent to client пока не перезапустишь сервер. Почему так?

Comment: Еще злит, что из метода .connect абсолютно невозможно забрать данные, записать их в переменную или массив. Уже и промисы пробовал - ничего не выходит. Либо закидываешь ответ БД напрямую в ответ сервера, либо работаешь с ними только внутри функции. Вот бы записать кол-во совпадений в переменную и спокойно перейти  условию дальше...

Comment: думаю, правильнее было бы написать `"SELECT * FROM utilisateurs where login = ? limit 1`